# How do I commit changes to a repository while I am 1 behind and 2 ahead?

Tags: github, repository, atlassian-sourcetree, git-commit, git-pull

So I am 1 behind and 2 ahead on this GitHub repository.
When I got to pull to solve the 1 behind problem it gives me this output:

```
git --no-optional-locks -c color.branch=false -c color.diff=false -c color.status=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree fetch origin 
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm not really sure what this means and would like to solve this issue as soon as possible and upload some files onto the repository.
I'm a beginner when it comes to GitHub and SourceTree.

Answer (score 0):

It means the way SourceTree uses SSH fails to authenticate you on GitHub.

Check first if, in command line, `ssh -T git@github.com` works: see "[Testing your SSH connection](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/testing-your-ssh-connection)".

Then check sourceTree settings: as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27304833/6309), I would recommend using the OpenSSH client, not the putty one (assuming you have used `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -m PEM` to generate your ssh private/public key pair, and not putty, or that you are not on Windows)