# How to bypass SourceTree asking for key passphrase?

Tags: git, ssh, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I just reinstalled SourceTree in my system but it keep asking for the passphrase. I set that up years ago and have no idea what that would be. I tried all passwords that I could remember but it says bad passphrase. Is there any way to avoid it? I tried the below steps but that didn't help:

[image]

[image]

Thoughts?

Comment: To start with, it shouldn't be asking for a passphrase for a .pub file. .pub files aren't passphrase-protected.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried all passwords that I could remember but it says bad passphrase. Is there any way to avoid it?

Not really: you would need to recreate the key, with a new passphrase if you want:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

And register your [new OpenSSH key to SourceTree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27304833/6309).